# Not able to Application icon in google workspace marketplace SDK store listing configuration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I want to list one app on the Google Workspace marketplace app. When I do store listing required configuration. I am not able to upload an icon. I have tried every format PNG, JPG, and GIF with the required dimensions. What could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that you might need to check in order to find out what is causing your issue. To start off, simple troubleshooting steps like clearing the cache/cookies or trying a different browser can help you isolate the issue. Verify the size and configuration of the image that you are trying to use since it can have issues if the size and specs are not in the acceptable limits. Also check the network connection settings and also firewalls that may be blocking the access. Lastly, you might need to verify the necessary permissions of your account. Here is the documentation for configuring your app in Workspace.[1] Hope this helps.

[1] https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk

Comment: I have already tried three browsers. and also I have created the same size of logo as per requirement. regarding the network connection, all things are working fine except this. and also I am uploading with super admin access. So that's also not the case. Also, I have asked google support but he is unable to understand the issue and is taking too much time to respond.

Comment: It worked after I had cleared the cookies in firefox.